# Salesforce Outbound call (Click To Dial) using Twilio Flex

Tags: lightning, configuration, opencti, twilio

I am trying to implement **Twilio Flex** for **Salesforce Open CTI**. I am using a twilio trial account. I have enabled Inbound calls to salesforce using twilio flex. Now I am trying to implement **Click-To-Dial** for salesforce **outbound call** **using twilio flex**. But I am stuck in making an Outbound call. When I click a phone number from the salesforce contact page, the twilio window pops up and shows a message '**Attempting Outbound call now**' then stops and no call is placed in the specified number.

A task is creating with this comment -

```
[Attempting] outbound voice. Details: PostData:
CallTo: -
CallFrom: NO_CALLER_ID
WorkflowSid: WW5fbcbf6ee9d199b13252baf6939ba3cc
TaskChannelSid: TC4a4c6f7cb0a3fb09a87cd27e0adfa8f8
WorkspaceSid: WSfcffdb601ba21fec6aa21389d11f5e85
WorkerContactUri: client:playwithpackage_2Dm1_40free_2Ddev_2Ecom
WorkerSid: WKce67db7d7e1e88aa4505542d493b69bf
WorkerName: playwithpackage-m1@free-dev.com
Priority: 999
Direction: outbound
TaskChannelUniqueName: voice
Direction: outbound
```

And every time I got this error when trying to make a outbound call

```
Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy 
directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-fbd8b58ceca1755f12efd1a1e2bd2a8f' 
chrome-extension: 'unsafe-eval' *.canary.lwc.dev *.visualforce.com 
https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/ https://static.lightning.force.com". 
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce 
('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Error: outbound calling disabled
    at assets.flex.twilio.com/releases/flex-ui/1.23.1/twilio-flex.min.js:1461
    at assets.flex.twilio.com/releases/flex-ui/1.23.1/twilio-flex.min.js:1461
    at Object.next (assets.flex.twilio.com/releases/flex-ui/1.23.1/twilio-flex.min.js:1461)
    at assets.flex.twilio.com/releases/flex-ui/1.23.1/twilio-flex.min.js:1461
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at i (assets.flex.twilio.com/releases/flex-ui/1.23.1/twilio-flex.min.js:1461)
    at e.startOutboundCall (assets.flex.twilio.com/releases/flex-ui/1.23.1/twilio-flex.min.js:1461)
    at e.<anonymous> (assets.flex.twilio.com/releases/flex-ui/1.23.1/twilio-flex.min.js:142)
    at assets.flex.twilio.com/releases/flex-ui/1.23.1/twilio-flex.min.js:142
    at Object.next (assets.flex.twilio.com/releases/flex-ui/1.23.1/twilio-flex.min.js:142)
(anonymous) @ assets.flex.twilio.com/twilio/flex-salesforce-integration/1.4.0/plugin-flex-salesforce-integration.js:1
```

[image: click to dial]

[image: flex pop up]

Any guidance to implement the salesforce outbound call using Twilio Flex will be great.

Comment: Do you see any error in the browser console logs?

Comment: Yes, I got a error every time. (updated in post)

Comment: The error 
`Refused to run the JavaScript URL because it violates the following Content Security Policy 
directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-fbd8b58ceca1755f12efd1a1e2bd2a8f' 
chrome-extension: 'unsafe-eval' *.canary.lwc.dev *.visualforce.com 
https://ssl.gstatic.com/accessibility/ https://static.lightning.force.com". 
Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce 
('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

Comment: As mentioned in https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000E3TuQAK ,  can you try making Twilio flex as default app for calling and let me know if it fixes the issue?

Comment: The answer mentioned in [https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000E3TuQAK](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000E3TuQAK) is for Ringcentral. And I could not find any option to make Twilio flex as default app for calling. Besides in 'Assigned App' section of a Profile 'Twilio Flex' is not listed to make it default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I am able to make **outbound calls** form **salesforce** by **Click To Dial/Dial Pad** using **Twilio Flex**. To solve the console error

```
Error: outbound calling disabled
```

and make the outbound call working, Firstly I had to **Enable** the **Dial Pad** in Twilio flex **Setting** in Twilio.  Then I had to set the **Caller Id** and other information there.
[image]

You can get more information here https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/dialpad/enable